# Is my proof of the equation $d=dx^i\wedge \partial_i$ correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

Let $M$ be some manifold, $x$ a chart on $U\subset M$ and $\omega$ a $p$-form such that
\begin{equation}
    \omega=\omega_I\wedge dx{}^I:=\sum_{1\leq i_1<\ldots<i_p\leq n}\omega_{i_1,\ldots,i_p}dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_p}
\end{equation}
on $U$. From [The Geometry of Physics](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139061377), page $141$:

> In any manifold the operation of exterior differentiation [...] can be written symbolically as $d = dx^j\wedge\partial/\partial x^j$; the operator $\partial/\partial x^j$ acts only on the
> coefficients.

Here is my attempt of a proof: We have
\begin{align}
&d\omega=d(\omega_Idx^I)=d(\omega_I\wedge dx^I)=d\omega_I\wedge dx^I+\omega_I\wedge ddx^I\\
&=d\omega_I\wedge dx^I+0=d\omega_I\wedge dx^I=d\omega_I\wedge dx^I=\partial_j\omega_Idx{}^j\wedge dx^I\\
&=dx{}^j\wedge \partial_j\omega_Idx^I=dx^j\wedge\partial_j\omega 
\end{align}
where we have defined $\partial_j(\omega_Idx^I):=(\partial_j\omega_I)dx^I$.

Is this correct? In particular, is it allowed to write $\omega_I dx^I=\omega_I\wedge dx^I$?

**Comment:** The definition of $\partial _i\omega$ might seem a bit weird, but I noticed that it also appears in other parts of the book:

From the overview before the first chapter:

> The electric field intensity is a $1$-form $\mathscr E$ and the magnetic field intensity is a $2$-form $\mathscr B$ and Faraday’s law says
> \begin{equation}
> d\mathscr E = −\frac{\partial \mathscr B}{\partial t}
> \end{equation}
> where $\partial \mathscr B/\partial t$ means take the time derivative of the components of $\mathscr B$.

From page $119$:

> We define the time derivative of an exterior form by differentiating each component\begin{equation}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\omega:=\frac{\partial\omega_I}{\partial t}dx^I
> \end{equation}

Thus I thought that maybe we can define $X\omega$ - where $X$ is a vector field and $\omega$ is a $k$-form - to be the $k$-form $X\omega:=X(\omega_I)dx^I$. If we can prove that the definition doesn't depend on the coordinate system, this would be well defined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $X\omega$ is not well defined. It's coordinate dependent. Consider the coordinate systems $x$ and $y$ in which $y = f(x)$ for some non-constant increasing and nonvanishing function (the manifold is $\mathbb{R}$ here). Consider the 1 form $\omega := dy = f'(x) dx$. Let $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{f'(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Then $X(dy) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (1) dy = 0$

And $X(dy) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f'(x) dx = \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)} dx \neq 0 $.

There is indeed an invariant formula for the exterior derivative. If $\omega$ was a 2-form: then

$$d\omega (X,Y) = X(\omega(Y)) - Y(\omega(X)) - \omega([X,Y])$$
for any vector fields $X,Y$.
The general invariant formula looks a little more complicated. Check it out on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_invariant_formula.

**EDIT**: Your formula for $d\omega$ is correct. In local coordinates,
$$d\omega = dx^i \wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \omega_I dx^I$$
which is indeed coordinate independent. That is how many authors define the exterior derivative actually. They define it locally in that way and show that this expression is coordinate independent, which shows that $d\omega$ is well defined globally. However, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \omega_I dx^I$ is not coordinate independent and so is not a well defined global 1-form as I show above.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer and most importantly, for proving my assumption wrong (I took me an hour to wrap my head around the entire calculation). To give a concrete counter example, we need a smooth bijective $f\colon\mathbb R\to U\subset\mathbb R$ with a smooth inverse, $f'(x)\neq 0$ everywhere and $f''(x)\neq 0$ somewhere. Polynomials don't work, but the arctan should work.

Comment: But $\mathrm{d}\omega=\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\partial_i\omega_Idx^I$ could still be right (as long as we don't mix two charts), couldn't it?

Comment: Yes that formula is right. And it actually happens to be coordinate independent. As in if you used any other coordinate system, then you also get $d\omega = dx^i \wedge \partial_i \omega_I dx^I$ with respect to that coordinate system.

Comment: Also it seems that $f(x) = x^3$ works also.

Comment: The inverse of $x^3$ isn't differentiable at $0$, is it?

Comment: Oh true but you can also consider the manifold to be $\mathbb{R} \setminus {0}$.

Comment: It's a bit weird, because if we put the result of my proof and your answer together, we get than in general $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\omega_I\mathrm{d}x^I\neq\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\tilde{\omega}_I\mathrm{d}\tilde{x}^I$, but $\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\omega_I\mathrm{d}x^I=\mathrm{d}\omega=\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\tilde{\omega}_I\mathrm{d}\tilde{x}^I$

Comment: I know that this is not necessarely a contradiction, but I wouldn't have expected that.

Comment: i completely agree it's a little surpising. $dx^i \wedge \partial_i \omega_I dx^I$ is coordinate independent, but $\partial_i \omega_I dx^I$ is coordinate dependent.

Comment: To get a better understanding of this, change coordinates and see how $dx^i \wedge \partial_i \omega_I dx^I = dy^i \wedge \partial_i \omega_I dy^I$. See exactly where that extra $dx^i $ plays a role in making all this coordinate independent.

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding the title

Actually the answer can be found in the book that I quoted:

- In my proof I used the **defining properties** of the differential, see theorem $2.53$.
- If we look at the proof of that theorem, then we see that the equation that I tried to prove is precisely the equation that is used to show the existence.

### Regarding the comment

If we consider a Galilean spacetime or a Minkowski spacetime (i.e. if we assume that the transition charts are all Galilei or Poincaré transformations), then it is easy to show that my $X\omega$ is well-defined (i.e. chart-independent) and equals $L_X\omega$. In addition, if we consider a fixed reference frame, then the vector field $\partial/\partial t$ is chart-independent. This justifies the parts in the book that I cited. See chapter $4$ for a great discussion of the Lie derivative.